# ms sql 2008 r2 rebuild index automatically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a db in MS SQL 2008 R2 I would like to know if there exists some utility (in MS Management Studio) or other which can automatically rebuild my indexes for a database.

By automatically I mean rebuilding once at week or at regular interval of time.

Comment: Yes I cannot find an answer, if you have a solution please let me know thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 4):

Under the Management folder, there is a Maintenance Plan folder.  You can right-click on that and select the Maintenance plan wizard.

If you want to go beyond that take a look here for widely used, highly flexible scripts that go well beyond the wizard:  http://ola.hallengren.com/

Answer (score 2):

See [How to: Rebuild an Index (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187874%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Rebuild Index Using Transact-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx#TsqlProcedureReorg).

Comment: Thanks I know about this, but it is not exactly what I'm looking for, I would like have this operation performed automatically at specific interval of time. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can use the T-SQL for rebuilding an index and [create a job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx).

Comment: Also see [Rebuild Index Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180074%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).